# Customizer textarea with script tag won't work in live preview

Tags: php, theme-customizer, sanitization

I have a simple textarea setup in the customizer that I want to use for including a 3rd party form.  In order to embed this form I need to paste in 2 script tags into the textarea.

This all works fine but **I can't seem to get the live preview to work when adding in the script tags**.  It does update when removing the script tags from the textarea but doesn't when I add them back in.  However, publishing the customizer and refreshing the frontend shows me the form correctly.

**Customizer Settings**

```
function theme_options($wp_customize) {

    // Add Panel
    $wp_customize->add_panel('footer_options',
        array(
            'title' => __('Footer Options'),
            'priority' => 210
        )
    );

    // Add Section
    $wp_customize->add_section('footer_options_newsletter_signup',
        array(
            'title' => __('Newsletter Signup'),
            'panel' => 'footer_options'
        )
    );

    // Add Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting('footer_options_newsletter_signup_textarea',
        array(
            'default' => '',
            'sanitize_callback' => ''
        )
    );

    // Add Control
    $wp_customize->add_control('footer_options_newsletter_signup_textarea',
        array(
            'label' => __('Cognito Script Tags'),
            'description' => esc_html__('Copy the code from Cognito and it will include a newletter signup form in the footer.'),
            'section' => 'footer_options_newsletter_signup',
            'type' => 'textarea'
        )
    );

};

add_action('customize_register', 'theme_options');
```

**Template Code**

```
<?php
    $newletter_signup = get_theme_mod('footer_options_newsletter_signup_textarea');
?>

<?php if($newletter_signup){ ?>
    <div id="newsletter">
        <div>
            <h2>Subscribe to <span>our newsletter</span></h2>
            <div class="form">
                <div class="cognito">
                    <?php echo $newletter_signup; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Notes**

- I removed any sanitization by setting `'sanitize_callback' => ''`
- I tried creating my own sanitization function that just returned the value
- Everything works as expected if I just paste in a string and not the `<script>` tags
- I realize I could include the script tags in the template so they don't have to be pasted into the customizer but that isn't ideal
- `$newletter_signup` is still empty in the preview if I only put in a `<script>` tag

---

**Update**

After some testing, this appears to only be an issue with Chrome, the script tag is generating the following error (in Chrome only).

> The XSS Auditor blocked access to 'http://localhost/?customize_changeset_uuid=d1fb81cd-ab2f-48bf-96c5-889972def725&customize_theme=my_theme&customize_messenger_channel=preview-2&customize_autosaved=on' because the source code of a script was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server did not send an 'X-XSS-Protection' header.

Everything works as expected in other browsers.

Comment: I implemented this and added the template code to my footer template. It's working how I expect it to. I tried the following script from the customizer and it's working as expected in the preview. `<script>var newDiv = window.document.createElement("div"); var newContent = window.document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!"); newDiv.appendChild(newContent); $('#newsletter').before(newDiv);</script>`

Comment: Interesting.  I pasted your code into my customizer field and I got the same results.  After digging some more, I noticed a JS error "The XSS Auditor blocked access".  I bet you are using FF or IE?  This appears to be a Chrome feature to block these requests.  I tested outside of Chrome and everything works.

Comment: Yep, I used Firefox for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I updated my question, maybe I will be able to find a work-around in Chrome.